# Eliminate the field index from database query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PDO to access my database (mysql / mssql).
When I'm reading all the records at once using:

```
$query = $pdoDb->prepare("
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table
");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

I'm getting result containing also the array index (duplicated data):

```
0: "1"
ShipCode: "1"

1: "ESPADA 1"
ShipName: "ESPADA 1"

2: ""
Hatches: "0"

3: "CARGO"
ShipType: "CARGO"
```

I would like to get the data as follow:

```
ShipCode: "1"
ShipName: "ESPADA 1"
Hatches: "0"
ShipType: "CARGO"
```

How do I query just to field type results without the duplicated indexes?

Thanks,

Comment: You can always check out the other parameters for fetchAll() on the php site to see if any of them fix your problem: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to avoid duplicates you must `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
$query = $pdoDb->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
      *
    FROM
      table
");
```

To fetch only column names and omit the numeric index, go:

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```